# How can i correctly decorate PyQt callback function?

Tags: python, pyqt4, python-decorators

In python PyQt signal's callback functions also have "hidden" parameter "state". This parameter is making harder function decoration by user-defined decorators.

My example of code and a decorator. In my solution i have to admit TypeErrors, caused by incorrect parameters count, for every callback without lambda, otherwice i can't decorate. Is there a better way, in which i can exclude admitting TypeError ?  Can i ignore "state" parametr somehow else in my decorator?

Code example : decorator and program example.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

def decor(func_fuc):
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        #do something
        try:
            func_fuc(*args, **kwargs)
        except TypeError as TypE:
            if all(i in TypE.args[0] for i in ['takes', 'positional', 'argument' ,'but', 'given']):
                args = tuple([args[ar] for ar in range(len(args)-1)])
                func_fuc(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                raise TypE
        #etc
    return new_func

class MainWind(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    @decor
    def __init__(self,parent=None,geometry = QtCore.QRect(100,100,800,800)):
        super(MainWind, self).__init__(parent,geometry=geometry)
        self.pushik = QtGui.QPushButton(
            self, clicked = self.vasa
            ,geometry = QtCore.QRect(100,100,50,50), text = 'vasa'
        )

        self.petjaBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(
            self, clicked = lambda state : self.petja()
            ,geometry = QtCore.QRect(100,200,50,50), text = 'petja'

        )

        self.someBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(
            self, clicked = self.someBtnClick
            ,geometry = QtCore.QRect(100,300,50,50), text = 'someBtn'
        )

        self.show()
    #@decor
    def vasa(*args):
        print('vasa call')
        print(args) #(<__main__.MainWind object at 0x018FF940>, False)
    #@decor
    def petja(*args):
        print('petja call')
        print(args) #(<__main__.MainWind object at 0x018FF940>,)

    def someBtnClick(self): # usual usage
        print('someBtnClick call')
        # signature : accept only "self", but works fine on button click(with 2 params, self and state)
        # if i write empty decorator, that just returns original call, i will get typeError (reason - extra argument)
        #how to decorate without admitting "argument" TypeError?

app=QtGui.QApplication([])
wind = MainWind()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you examine `inspect.getfullargspec()` of decorated functions, you'll see that their signatures are "wong". 
See [Fix Your Decorators](https://hynek.me/articles/decorators/) , [wrapt library](https://wrapt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

But unfortunately writing the decorator using `@wrapt.decorator()` still don't solve the problem, though `getfullargspec()` looks correct. It seems that the PyQt do yet another code inspection to count the function attributes.